# Какую версию Unreal Engine выбрать?

Tags: unreal-engine

У меня достаточно слабый пк, не вытягивает версию Unreal Engine 4.27, если я установлю версию 4.13, я лишусь каких либо возможностей которые есть в 4.27?

Comment: Очевидно, что 4.27 "богаче" чем 4.13. А как вы себе представляете, что 4.13 по возможностям равна 4.27, тогда зачем 4.27 вообще существует? ))

Comment: Вам если обучаться, то не переживайте в разности версий. В любом случае ВЫ точно ничего не потеряете! Напротив, лишь приобретете.